# How to handle invalid e-mail in password recovery using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise

I'm trying to change redirect response after user submits an invalid e-mail (not stored in database).

To handle when the email is stored, following this [instruction](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-URL-after-sending-reset-password-instructions) it's easy to figure out.
But, how can I set the redirect response when the e-mail is invalid?

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to start by following the instructions that you linked to in order to create a custom `passwords_controller.rb`.  Then you need to override the `create` method from the original `devise/passwords_controller.rb`

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L12

Instead of `respond_with(resource)` when the email is not successfully sent you could redirect to wherever you want.